# Finding if estimator is correct using method of moments

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

b) Is $\hat\theta$ an absolutely correct estimator? Explain.

For the point a) I got $\nu_1=E(X)=\int_0^\theta x^2\frac{2}{\theta^2}dx$ which is $\frac{2}{3}\theta$. And $\nu_1=\bar X$(sample mean). So $\hat \theta=\frac{3}{2}\bar X$.

And for they point b) we have to check if $E(\hat \theta)=\theta$ and $lim_{n\to \infty} V(\hat \theta)=0$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\theta^2$ in the denominator of the pdf ?

Comment: @TrivialPursuit - it should, and is in the integral

Comment: Your approach is sound, and the estimator is *consistent* since $E(\hat{\theta})\rightarrow\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$E(\hat \theta)=\frac{3}{2}E(\bar X)=\frac{3}{2}\mu$ is not a problem. It in fact shows $\hat \theta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$; it is also a consistent estimator as $\mathrm{Var}(\bar X) \to 0$ in probability as the sample size increases.

To illustrate the actual problem here, suppose you happen to see the data $7,1,5,3,6,2$.

- What would your estimate of  $\theta$ be?
- Would your all your data satisfy $0 \lt x \lt \hat \theta$?

Comment: Yes, Var converges to zero, but $\frac{3}{2}\mu$ I don't think is equal to $\theta$

Comment: Or is $E(\bar X)=E(X)$? In this case we have $\frac{3}{2}E(\bar X)=\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \theta$

Comment: $\mu=E(X)=\frac23 \theta$ and $\theta= \frac32 \mu$ and $E(\bar X)=E(X)$ are all correct statements here